# dynamically set maximum number of requests in envoy rate limit service

Tags: rate-limiting, envoyproxy

We use Envoy [rate limit service](https://github.com/envoyproxy/ratelimit) to limit the number of requests hitting our service.

Deployment is similar to this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: envoy-rate-limiter
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      service: envoy-rate-limiter
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict: "true"
      labels:
        service: envoy-rate-limiter
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - weight: 100
            podAffinityTerm:
              labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                  - key: service
                    operator: In
                    values:
                      - router-$(ConfigMap.BRANCH)
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1001
        fsGroup: 1001
      containers:
      - name: envoy-rate-limiter
        image: envoyproxy/ratelimit:e059638d
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
            name: http
            protocol: TCP
          - containerPort: 8081
            name: grpc
            protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
          - name: ratelimit-config
            mountPath: /data/ratelimit/config
            readOnly: true
        env:
          - name: REDIS_TLS
            value: "false"
        command: ["/bin/ratelimit"]
      volumes:
        - name: ratelimit-config
          configMap:
            name: ratelimit-config
```

Configuration of rate limit service is basically this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ratelimit-config
data:
  config: |
    ---
    domain: router
    descriptors:
    - key: "METHOD"
      rate_limit:
        unit: second
        requests_per_unit: 2000
        name: overall_limit
```

I'd like the value of requests_per_unit to change if some other services scales up. How can I achieve it?